# If $2x^4\dot{x}\ddot{x}+4x^3\dot{x}^3=-x\dot{x}$, show that $x^4\dot{x}^2=\frac{1}{2}(x_0^2-x^2)$, where $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I know that $\dot{x}\ddot{x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(\dot{x}^2)}{dt}$, $x\dot{x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(x^2)}{dt}$ and $x^3\dot{x}^3=\big(\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(x^2)}{dt}\big)^3$.

So this gives $x^4\frac{d(\dot{x}^2)}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{d(x^2)}{dt}\big)^3=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(x^2)}{dt}$.

I feel like I need to integrate w.r.t $t$, but I'm not sure how to deal with the 2nd term on the LHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2x^4\dot{x}\ddot{x}+4x^3\dot{x}^3=-x\dot{x} \\ \implies x^4 (2\dot x \ddot x) + (4x^3 \dot x)(\dot x^2) = -\frac 12 \cdot 2x\dot x \\ \implies \frac{d}{dt} (x^4 \dot x^2)= -\frac 12\frac{d}{dt} x^2$$

Integrating,
$$x^4 \dot x^2 =-\frac 12 x^2+ C $$

Plug in $t=0,x=x_0, \dot x=0$ to get $C=\frac 12 x_0^2 $, and your goal.

Answer (score 0):

To help your intuition along in such cases of second order autonomous differential equations, it is often useful to make the substitution $\dot x=u(x)$ along segments of a hypothetical solution where it is strictly monotonous. Then $\ddot x=u'(x)u(x)$ and the equation becomes
$$
2x^4u^2u'+4x^3u^3=-xu \implies u=0~\lor ~ 2x^4uu'+4x^3u^2=-x
$$
This now can be identified as a linear equation in $u(x)^2$. Then continue as usual.